# PHP: How to convert from .caf to .mp3 format?

Tags: php, api, mp3, caf

I wonder if there is any way to convert the caf files to mp3 files using any api or any other methods for my web application built on php. I don't know this is possible in php or not.

I know i can use `pacpl input.caf -to mp3` on my server to make it work but i have shared hosting and i would like to know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pacpl input.caf -to mp3` works at bash, why not call it from PHP like so:

`shell_exec("pacpl input.caf -to mp3");`

You may or may not need to reconfigure the permissions or use `sudo` in there depending on the host server config.

Comment: Yes i know that but for that i need to install pacpl on my server and that is not permitted. That's why i am searching for an api which can do this.

Comment: Where is the shared hosting?

Comment: I tried this command on my ec2 and it gives me error: Perl Audio Converter - 4.0.5

Converting:  [20130623125823.caf] -> [mp3] decode failed with exit status: 256


Total files converted: 0, failed: 1